# Azure Active Directory B2C navigation failures using Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

using the built in sign-up and sign-in policy with azure AD, the user can signup and the account gets created, but the UI never returns back to the app.  It stays here

[image]

The same issue happens when testing the user flow in the azure portal.

I'm not sure what to do or where to go from here on testing this?

There are other little funny quirks that I notice also.  When the cancel button is clicked the UI never redirects back to the sign in page.  the loading progress bar moves across as if something should be happening but it never goes back to the previous page.

[image]

Same thing when trying to go forgot password page.

**EDIT**
here is a repo https://github.com/champcbg/AzureAdB2CTest with azure ad credentials stripped out that follows these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c the sign in and sign up work successfully i can see the results in azure, but the hand off never is given back to the android app.

[image: Code Block]

the code in the green block is executed and that is how the sign-in and sign-up pages are shown.  after either action the code never comes back to line 79 (red arrow).

but if the back button (on the phone) is pressed control is given back to the app, the code falls into the exception block as a "authentication_canceled" event.

Comment: Could you provide the code for us to test? You could try to override this `OnBackButtonPressed` event on your NavigationPage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT do you hitting the back button to solve cancel button? when the back navigation button is hit, the app navigates back to calling page (i.e. MainPage.xaml)

Comment: We could not confirm what cause this issue without code. Could you provide that? What do you do with the `OnBackButtonPressed` event? Which page do you want to back?

Comment: your right with the back navigation button it did take me back sign up to sign in page

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I have updated the posting with a code sample repo and setup link to the documentation and some more details what is happening in the app.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you debug the code, have you get the result from the green block? If not, i guess the await does not finished. Download the source file from the the link to test. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-azureadb2cauth/

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT code in my project matches that exactly the example from your link.  To answer your question, the await never is never coming back from the green block.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT to see if my setup in azure AD B2C was correct i even tried these https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Core/Features/LogOn/B2CConstants.cs setting and the same problem happened, creating an account and login events were never returned from the await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.  I was never able to solve the issue of the app coming back from the await.  I am leaning toward the error being that the active page was never not found again.  that is only an assumption that can not be confirmed.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

Following the code example for the project link above solved the problem.  The key differences from the original example are

1. Authentication was extracted to a service not bound to button clicks, which was actually my desired path anyway or in view models.
2. Parent Window locator service which is used in the android project

The complete solution was built by following these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c for creating the Azure AD resources and this for actually implementing the xamarin app https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native